# RecyclerView не правильно обрабатывает OnClickListerner

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(@NonNull final MyChildViewHodler childViewHolder, final int parentPosition, final int childPosition, @NonNull final Course child) {
    childViewHolder.childProgress.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lerning_child));
    childViewHolder.childProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    childViewHolder.imgCertification.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Log.e("MyLerningFragmentAdapter=CREATE", parentPosition + "  " + childPosition + "");

    if (parentPosition!=0){
        childViewHolder.rippleLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("MyLerningFragmentAdapter=CLICK", parentPosition + "  " + childPosition + "");
            }
        });
    }
```

Судя по всему я не так добавляю Listener. Как быть тогда?

Куда его добавить нужно чтобы заработало. Такая же проблема у меня была с ListView. Вот еще видео прикладываю. Чтобы было понятнее

[Видео с ошибкой](http://rgho.st/private/8rs97Zbcg/521a6a23b608cf5ec117f71d3fbda658)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecyclerView` использует созданные `ViewHolder`'ы повторно, для того, чтобы не создавать множество новых объектов при пролистывании длинного списка. При прокрутке списка, когда на экране появляется новый элемент, адаптер берёт один из использованных `ViewHolder`ов, которые ушли с экрана, и заполняет его новыми данными.

Т.к. у вас есть проверка

```
if (parentPosition != 0)
```

, при пролистывании наверх, когда на экране появляются элементы 0-го родителя, новый `OnClickListener` не устанавливается, а остаётся тем же самым, который был при создании `ViewHolder`'а, который используется для показа этого нового элемента.

**UPDATE**. Ответ на комментарий.

Можно например так:

```
@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(
        @NonNull final MyChildViewHodler childViewHolder,
        final int parentPosition,
        final int childPosition,
        @NonNull final Course child
) {
    int colorResId;
    switch (parentPosition) {
        case 4:
            colorResId = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lerning_child_red);
            break;
        default:
            colorResId = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lerning_child);
            break;
    }

    childViewHolder.childProgress.setTextColor(colorResId);
    ...
}
```

Но лучше конечно не завязываться именно на номер, а использовать дополнительное поле в классе `Parent`, которое для 4 имело бы одно значение, а для всех остальные другое. И тогда использовать что-то типа:

```
    Parent parent = getParent(parentPosition);
    int colorResId = context.getResources().getColor(parent.getColorFlag()
            ? R.color.lerning_child_red
            : R.color.lerning_child);
```

Comment: А как быть Если к примеру TextView цвет текста Black по умолчанию.
Я хочу поменять в 4 позиции цвет текста на красный. Как мне это правильно сделать. А то у меня кроме 4 позиции и другие тоже красными и черными становятся.

Answer (score 1):

Видео посмотреть не могу. Попробуйте вот так

```
 childViewHolder.rippleLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (parentPosition == 0)
                    return;
                Log.e("MyLerningFragmentAdapter=CLICK", parentPosition + "  " + childPosition + "");
            }
        });
```